# AVD showing only "Android" in emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

```
Android Launch!
[2013-06-17 15:38:53 - Numberconverter] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-17 15:38:53 - Numberconverter] Performing com.example.channu.Numbersystem activity launch
[2013-06-17 15:39:00 - Numberconverter] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AMMA'
[2013-06-17 15:39:05 - Numberconverter] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-17 15:39:05 - Numberconverter] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [faq] to understand why your question does barely fit the rules for this community. Please provide more information and don't just put console output in the question body. Also this kind of question was asked hundreds of times, have you searched here and on google?

Comment: edit the AVD and try providing more RAM to it...

Comment: it displaying only android ....recently i have changed the workspace...from that any problemmm??

Comment: No nothing to do with the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong.

```
Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Means that it is actually waiting for the OS to be loaded on the emulator. This usually takes a few minutes depending upon the configuration of the system you are using.

Just wait for a few minutes and you would be able to see the usual Android OS loaded on the emulator.

The usual console output when you launch an app on a new emulator is something like:

```
[2013-06-17 16:06:52 - FirstRun] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-17 16:06:52 - FirstRun] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-17 16:08:00 - FirstRun] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-17 16:08:00 - FirstRun] Uploading FirstRun.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-17 16:08:01 - FirstRun] Installing FirstRun.apk...
[2013-06-17 16:08:30 - FirstRun] Success!
[2013-06-17 16:08:30 - FirstRun] Starting activity dev.swm.firstrun.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-06-17 16:08:32 - FirstRun] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=dev.swm.firstrun/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Delete your AVD and create a new one, preferably with higher RAM.

Comment: Well, in that case, looks like you would need a fresh installation.

Comment: still waiting for long time and nothing happen .. votes up for the explanation

Comment: Does your AVD have enough RAM allocated ?

Comment: Sometimes it you have tu turn on "Use host GPU" sometimes you have to turn it off... (but that is AFTER "HOME" is launched...)

Answer (score 0):

you can, wait for few seconds and then right click on the project and click run as Android application once again.

also, The only thing that works for me is the combination of three other good answers:

1- Project -> Clean

2- Delete all the AVDs and create new ones

3- If an attempt to run still hangs too long on 'Waiting for HOME' (over two minutes) or the emulator keeps rebooting every minute or so, try Run as Android App several times, choosing the same existing emulator instance (I always choose runs manually).

It's odd that no one has a clue why this problem comes up, what causes it or what is going on internally. The only clue I can supply is that DDMS shows a few lines like "Class not found for preloading: libcore.base.CollectionUtils" during the 'Waiting for HOME' pause.

if not try doing that and see if you can start & see if everything 
works.

1) try using Emulator command

2) in Eclipse, Window->Adnroid SDK & AVD manager ->Virtual Devices, 
then select the AVD, press Start button

Answer (score 0):

After you see the starting as shown above by swayam's answer in Eclipse "Console", "charging" screen appears, but then I pressed the "Menu" button on the right side and my program displayed and functions correctly.  Just a newbie trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a memory Problem. Increase the ammount of RAM, I had the same problem and increasing the RAM worked.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I set higher ram 756MB and then clicked on use host GPU and it did work after that. Win8 and used Nexus5 emulator API 19.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Avd of the same Api you using and try it will work

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem and managed to solve it by disabling Hyper-V (provided that you are running a Windows machine).
To do that, go to Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs -> Turn Windows Features on or off -> Uncheck Hyper-V

There is one thing though: the Hyper-V feature is not available in Home versions of Windows. Also disabling it prevents you from using Windows Phone emulators, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Even the side buttons were not appearing. I increased the ram from 512 to 750mb, and it worked like a charm.